# Running a command on every file in a folder, then saving output

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, batch-file

I am new to writing batch scripts and was hoping for some help.

I have a folder of images. I want to cURL each of these images, one by one, to an image classifier I made on the web. This will then send me a result.

I then want to save the response of the server into a file - let's keep it simple a say a CSV, in this format:

```
File, Response
```

So I know to run the Batch on each folder, I can do the following -

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b c:\') do echo curl -X POST -F "images_file=@%%f" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key=abcdefgh&version=2016-05-20"*
```

I know, I can somehow pipe the results into an output file using ">>".

I don't know how to put this together, and how to create the CSV as I am running the batch script. Can anyone help? I think I am 90% there just new to batch scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in powershell :
Change the placeholders as per your requirement.

```
$dir_files=Get-ChildItem  "C:\"
foreach($file in $dir_files)
{
$result=Invoke-WebRequest 'https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key=abcdefgh&version=2016-05-20' -Method Post -Headers 'images_file=@%%f'
$result | ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File "D:\outputfile.csv" -Append -Force
}
```

I just gave you the way to set off. I didn't go through the complete batch code.
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use batch, you can do:

```
@echo
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set imagedir=C:\
set csvfile="C:\results.csv"

FOR %%G IN ("%imagedir%*") DO (
    set resultfile=%%G.out
    echo curl -X POST -F "images_file=@%%G" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key=abcdefgh&version=2016-05-20"* -o "!resultfile!"
    echo %%G, !resultfile! >> %csvfile%
)

EndLocal
exit /b 0
```

I am not that experienced with `curl` so I'm not able to verify the correctness of your curl command and let the `echo` before it. But I do know that you can actually specify a file to write the output to in Windows with the `-o` flag.
The [`FOR`](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) command (without any flag/option) is another way to loop through files in a directory. If you still want to use the `for /f %%f in ('dir /b ...') do`-style (perhaps because of the order in which you want to treat your images), you can simply replace the line `FOR %%G IN ("%imagedir%*") DO (` with `for /f %%f in ('dir /b "%imagedir%"') DO (`. I saved the directory in the variable `imagedir`, it's then easier to change. But if you change it, don't forget the `\` at the end (if you use my for-command) and don't add double quotes (I add them in the `FOR` command). Be aware that this will treat **all FILES** in the directory. You can **specify extensions** if you want by using `"%imagedir%\*.jpg" "%imagedir%\*.gif"` for example for only GIF and JPEG images.
As last I'll say that I added `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). It's actually only needed because I saved the name of the file where the result of the `curl` operation will be saved, in the variable `resultfile`. In batch, a `FOR` -block (`FOR ... ( ... )`), and other blocks delimited with `( )` (as `IF`-blocks), are parsed as one single command (as if they were written on line). It is not really possible to change the value of a variable and read that new value in the same command (or same line) without using some special "tricks". Delayed expansion is one of them. When you use delayed expansion on a variable, you surround it with `!` instead of `%`. As `resultfile` will change in each iteration, I use `!resultfile!` instead of `%resultfile%`.
If you don't want to save the name of the outputfile in a variable, you can remove the use of the variable and the delayed expansion (remove the `EndLocal` at the end too).

Good luck!